# how to set the sample size to run a query on specified number of records

Tags: json, elasticsearch

When extracting data the total number of influencers on each index differs To ensure a consistent sample size across all index, can we maintain a base sample size, for examples 100 index, how to write a search query limiting to 100 records

how to write a search query limiting to 100 records, not to return value but to write a query on the limited records

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.